# Invalid database name: no configured connection named

Tags: sql-server, symfony, propel2

I tried to search somewhere, but haven't found any answers.
Here is my problem :

I'm developing a website, using Symfony 3 and Propel 2. i've got some bundle connected to my own database, it works perfectly.

I've one bundle which should be connected to an other db (on a Microsoft SQL Server). The problem is, i can't connect to the db.

Here is my config.yml

```
propel:
    database:
      connections:
          myconnection:
              adapter:    "pdo_mssql"
              classname:  Propel\Runtime\Adapter\MSSQL\MssqlDebugPDO
              dsn:        "host=MyHOST;dbname=DBname"
              user:       "user"
              password:   "password"
              attributes:
```

All of my options are correct, i was able to connect to this db with [DBeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/) (a database manager).

When i try

```
bin/console propel:database:reverse myconnection
```

i've got this error

```
[Propel\Generator\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]                        
Invalid database name: no configured connection named 
`host=MyHOST;dbname=DBname;user=user;password=password`.
```

So, could someone please help me ?

If you need more informations, just ask for it, and sorry for my english

ag.

Comment: It appears you need to set your host/db/user/password to actual values, and not use the placeholders that were in the config file.

Comment: I'm already using real values to set these options :)